# Saxon-CE pass variable tree as parameter to XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, parameter-passing, saxon

I'm using Saxon-CE to transform an XML File (XML to XML) based on a users's input.
I have an XML File looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XML>
    <Item name="i'm allowed"></Item>
    <Item name="me too"></Item>
    <Item name="not allowed"></Item>
    <Item name="me neiter"></Item>
<XML>
```

I have a JavaScript function that filters an XML File based on the Items a user selected befor from checkboxes (in this case one selected "i'm allowed" and "me too"). I want to save the selection of the user to a file and pass it to the XSLT 2.0 File as a variable:

```
<!-- allowed.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AllowedItems>
        <Item name="i'm allowed"></Item>
        <Item name="me too"></Item>
</AllowedItems>
```

so that I can use it in my XSL File with:

```
<xsl:param name="AllowedItems" />
```

Is there a possibility to realize this? What I have so far:

```
function TransformXML() {
    xsltData = Saxon.requestXML("transformXML.xsl");
    xmlData = Saxon.requestXML("myxml.xml");
    var xsltProcessor = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(xsltData);

    <!-- ?? xsltProcessor.setParameter(); ?? -->    
    xmlItemData = Saxon.requestXML("allowed.xml");
    xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "AllowedItems", xmlItemData);
    <!-- ?? xsltProcessor.setParameter(); ?? -->    

    var result = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlData);
        }
```

Can I pass the parameter in another way? Maybe serialize the allowed.xml? I'm not sure if there is a solution for this.

The problem is that I can't use the include function because I will have more "allowed.xsl" files and with include I can't choose the right file.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you really have two XSLT documents, `transformXML.xsl` and `allowed.xsl`? If the `allowed.xsl` solely contains XML data, why don't you simply use a normal XML document with the `Item` elements?

Comment: I could also save it as XML File, I edited my question. How to achieve it with this new situation? Can I pass an XML file as parameter?

Comment: According to http://saxonica.com/ce/user-doc/1.1/index.html#!api/xslt20processor/setParameter you should be able to pass in a node so `xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "AllowedItems", xmlItemData);` looks fine. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Also, you don't need to do `xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltData);` if you already supplied the stylesheet when creating the XSLTProcessor.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the include function"? Do you mean xsl:include? That is used only for including XSLT stylesheet modules, not XML data files.

Comment: I meant that I could also save the variable itself in a seperate xsl file and include it then. But it's better to pass as parameter because I don't know the filename exactly.
I think it should work like this but somehow I don't get any result.

Comment: I receive following error:

"SaxonCE.XSLT20Processor 08:03:20.791
SEVERE: Exception java.lang.ClassCastException in invokeTransform: null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014112102.html I have put together an example that works for me with current versions of Firefox and IE on Windows 8.1.

The code does not pass in a DOM node created with `Saxon.requestXML`, rather it simply passes in the URL of the XML document to be loaded and then within XSLT it uses `doc($param)` to read in the document.

I have used that approach as indeed trying to pass in a DOM document node created with `Saxon.requestXML` causes an exception as you have reported.

The working code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Saxon CE test</title>
    <script src="../saxonceDebug/Saxonce.nocache.js"></script>
    <script>
    function onSaxonLoad()
    {
      Saxon.setLogLevel('SEVERE');

      var xslt = Saxon.requestXML("test2014112102.xsl")
      var xsltProc = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(xslt);

      var input = Saxon.requestXML("test2014112101.xml");

      var filterUrl = "test2014112102.xml";

      xsltProc.setParameter(null, "filter", filterUrl);

      var result = xsltProc.transformToDocument(input);

      var resultString = Saxon.serializeXML(result);

      console.log(resultString);
      var pre = document.createElement('pre');
      pre.textContent = resultString;
      document.body.appendChild(pre);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Saxon CE Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

where the XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="filter" select="()"/>

<xsl:variable name="filter-doc" select="if (doc-available($filter)) then doc($filter) else ()"/>

<xsl:key name="by-value" match="item" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[not(key('by-value', ., $filter-doc))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It also works for me to pass in an XML DOM document returned as `responseXML` of an `XMLHttpRequest`, as done in http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014112103.html. It seems however, that Saxon CE should be able to consume the result of its own `Saxon.requestXML` method.

Comment: Thanks so much it's working perfectly! I agree with you that Saxon CE should be able to handle it's own object. Right now I'm just happy that it works.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again with this issue, but I have another example where I want to pass a created node (jquery) as a paramater to the XSLT file in the same way I did it here.

var items = $('<AllowedItems/>');
$.each( myitems, function( index, value ){
 items.append($('<Item  />').attr('ID', value)); 
   });

according to Saxon-CE documentation the parameter can be a node as well but I receive the same ClassCastException Error. 
Do you also have a solution for this?

Comment: I think that JQuery creates some kind of wrapper object around the DOM node so try passing in `$(items).get(0)` to Saxon. But that is just a suggestion, I have never tried that. If it does not work then I think it is better you post a new question.

Comment: I did some reading on the JQuery support for creating XML and it looks like `$('<foo/>')` basically only makes sense to create HTML elements, not pure XML (for instance, http://jsfiddle.net/qf9mb0fd/ outputs the XHTML namespace, not the SVG namespace). So you might be better off to use the W3C DOM to construct XML DOM elements instead of trying to use JQuery.